# Set Background in a LinearLayout from byte array

Tags: android

I have a LinearLayout with a default Background, but in some circumstances I need to set a custom Background from a byte[] data from Blob object in SQL Database.
I alreay have made the custom Adapter but I have no idea how do the image part.

```
if (Ad.getAd_image().length > 0) {
    //Ad.getAd_image() is a byte[] object
    ad_image_layout.setBackground(???);
}
```

Comment: You should edit your title to reflect what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can achieve by 2 ways,
1. If you have direct byte[] you can use

```
byte[] b = //your data;
Drawable image = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length));
```

If you have input stream you can use this

```
InputStream is = //your input stream;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

Comment: Great, this is the final piece of code

if (Ad.getAd_image().length > 0) {
                Drawable image = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(Ad.getAd_image(), 0, Ad.getAd_image().length));
                ad_image_layout.setBackground(image);
            }

Answer (score 1):

do this

```
Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(Ad.getAd_image(),0,Ad.getAd_image().length);

Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);

LinearLayout l;
l=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_id) 
l.setBackground(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `decodeByteArray` methods of [`BitmapFactory`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html).  The byte array must be in one of the [supported image formats](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html#image-formats).